# Fix a git push that depends on abandoned commit

Tags: git, version-control, gerrit

I accidentally did the command `git commit` when I should've done `git commit --amend`, then I proceeded to `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master` and abandoned the accidental `git commit`.

This obviously caused problems because I have a commit based on top of an abandoned commit. I have been advised by a colleague to run `git reset --soft HEAD^` which undid my previous commit

Am I back to where I started at the very beginning before my first accidental `git commit` or do I have other commands to run before I am out of the woods?

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "abandoned" the commit?

Comment: @JanHudec we use a website/software called gerrit at code.throg.<company.com where each employees commits show, we can do a number of git-related things on there such as `rebase` and `abandon`

Comment: If you use Gerrit, it must be mentioned. Because those things are _Gerrit_-related. Plain git does not have any "abandon" operation.

Comment: Ok. Now the question is what is actually the problem. Abandon basically undoes the `git push ...:refs/for/master`. If you do another push that includes that commit, the commit will be part of the new merge request and will not be abandoned in there, since it is a new merge request.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following steps in Gerrit:

1. Go to the abandoned change (with the first commit)
2. Click on "Restore" button
3. Approve/submit the change
4. Go to the second change (with the second commit)
5. Approve/submit the change